# Predicate checking equality of property from different objects of same class

Tags: java, java-stream

Using Java 8 Streaming API, I want to filter a collection of objects by checking equality between some properties of a sample object of same type, like

```
myFooCollection.stream().filter(foo -> foo.getBar().getBaz().equals(fooSampleObject.getBar().getBaz()));
```

Since I want to apply several filters of the same structure, but with different property path, is there a way to get this done in a convenient way? (for example with a custom predicate, which takes the property path as parameter?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Predicate which tests for equality to `fooSampleObject` by passing it and the `Function` to a method the following way:

```
private static <T,R> Predicate<T> getEqualsPredicate(T foo, Function<T, R> trFunction) {
    R apply = trFunction.apply(foo);
    Predicate<R> p = Predicate.isEqual(apply);
    return z -> p.test(trFunction.apply(z));
}
```

Then you can use the the following way:

```
List<Foo> result = myFooCollection.stream()
        .filter(getEqualsPredicate(fooSampleObject, (Foo f) -> f.getBar().getBaz()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `equals` method if the equality conditions there are what you need.  If you need different conditions, a custom predicate will work.  The simplest way would probably be a custom predicate that takes your `fooSampleObject` as a constructor parameter and does all the necessary checks in the `test` method.